# WordPress - Create new Page/Article with preloaded gutenberg blocks

Tags: wordpress, gutenberg-blocks

It is possible to create new pages, articles, or custom post types with an already pre-defined layout made up of Gutenberg blocks, which are not removable but you can add other new blocks?

Comment: Read this - https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-templates/#custom-post-types and how to lock it - https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-templates/#locking

Comment: Wow! Very useful. Thank you, Martin!